# Strictly singular operators and their adjoints

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

This is a question I thought about a while back and figured I'd throw it out there to see if anyone has some insight that I am missing.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be infinite dimensional separable Banach spaces.

A bounded linear operator $T:X \to Y$ is called strictly singular if its restriction to any infinite dimensional subspace $Z$ of $X$ is not an isomorphism. There is a lot of literature related to these operators especially in the past 20 years. Another, not as well studied, class of operators (introduced by Pelczynski) are the strictly cosingular operators. An operator $T: X \to Y$ is strictly cosingular if for any subspace $Z$ of $Y$ of infinite codimension, the operator $Q_Z T$ is not onto (here $Q_Z:Y \to Y/Z$ is the canonical quotient). An easy characterization of being strictly singular is that for every weak*-closed subspace $W$ of $Y^* $ the restriction of $T^* $ (the Banach space adjoint of $T$) on $W$ is not an isomorphism.

Using this characterization it is easy to see that $T^* $ is strictly singular implies that $T$ is strictly cosingular (if $T^* $ is not an isomorphism restricted to any subspace then it is certainly not when restricted to a weak* closed subspace.) Pelczynski observed that the inclusion $i:c_0 \to \ell_\infty$ is a counterexample to the converse ($i$ is stictly cosingular but $i^*$ is a projection).

We are interested in finding out when the converse does hold.

George Androulakis and I proved that if $T:X \to Y$ is strictly cosingular and $Y^* $ has the property that every subspace contains a bounded complete basic sequence then $T^* $ is strictly singular (this is not all that hard). In particular this is true when $Y^* $ is separable.

Finally I get to my question:

**Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are separable and $T: X \to Y$ is strictly cosingular. Is $T^* $ strictly singular?**

A counterexample would include a space $Y$ with non-separable dual and an operator with $T: X \to Y$ such that $T^* $ was not an isomorphism any weak*-closed subspace but managed to be an isomorphism on a norm-closed subspace.

Another observation: Assume that $T^* $ is not strictly singular and suppose the $T^* $ restricted to $Z$ in $Y^* $ is an isomorphism. By Gowers' dichomotomy either $Z$ contains unconditional basic sequence or an HI subspace. If the former holds mimicking what George and I did one can produce a weak* closed subspace which $T^* $ preserves isomorphically. In the latter case you have that $T^* $ preserves a copy of a norm-closed HI subspace that has no reflexive subspace (really nasty stuff). A counterexample then would have to be an operator that preserved a norm-closed HI space but not any weak* closed space that contained it.

I'm not sure how deep (or relevant) this question is, but it is something I wondered about for a while.

Comment: A naive question whose answer may be well-known: Is it true that if $X^\ast$ is isomorphic to $\ell_1$, then $X$ necessarily admits a quotient isomorphic to $c_0$? If the answer to this question is *no*, then an isomorphic embedding $X\longrightarrow C([0,1])$, where $X^\ast\approx \ell_1$ and $X$ admits no quotient isomorphic to $c_0$, provides a counterexample. I have in mind the somewhat-reflexive isomorphic preduals of $\ell_1$ handed down to us from Bourgain and Delbaen, but I don't know whether they have a quotient isomorphic to $c_0$. Also, have you looked at the work of A.K. Snyder?

Comment: Yes, Philip.  It follows from my old weak$^*$ basic sequence paper with Rosenthal, although this special case might have been known earlier.

Comment: Thanks, Bill. It is good to see the ask-johnson tag at work :) .

Comment: Philip: Thanks for the tip about the papers from Snyder. I had not looked at these. Out of curiosity, what is your argument to show that the map $X \to C([0,1]) $ is strictly cosingular.

Comment: Your welcome, Kevin. I don't actually know if there's anything in Snyder's papers, but they came up in a Google search. Anyway, to the requested argument: let $X^\ast\approx\ell_1$ and $T:X \longrightarrow C([0,1])$ an isomorphic embedding, and suppose that $Z\subseteq C([0,1])$ is such that $C([0,1])/Z$ is infinite dimensional and $Q_ZT$ is surjective. Then $C([0,1])/Z$ is nonreflexive since its dual is isomorphic to a subspace of $\ell_1$ via the mapping $(Q_ZT)^\ast$. Thus $Q_Z$ is nonweakly compact, hence $C([0,1])/Z$ contains a copy of $c_0$ by Pelczynski's theorem. By Soczyk's theorem...

Comment: you can even assume if you want that $C([0,1])/Z$ is isomorphic to $c_0$. Hence my question whether $c_0$ is a quotient of every isomorphic $\ell_1$ predual. The reason I thought to look at $\ell_1$ prequels is that a natural place to look is operators acting a space $X$ such that $X^\ast$ is known to have a fixing result for operators *into* $X^\ast$, leading to non-strict singularity for the adjoint; because of Pelczynski, we know that non-weakly compact ops into $L_1(\mu)$ fix a copy of $\ell_1$. I don't think I know of fixing results for operators *into* for any other spaces.

Comment: I think I also thought to look at $C([0,1])$ because it bears many similarities to the space $\ell_\inty$ from Pelczynski's example. Of course, it still may be that an embedding of a BD space into $C(K)$ with $K$ uncountable and metrizable is strictly cosingular, but you'll need some extra argument to get there. I suppose one could (if looking for a counterexample) look at the canonical embeddings $X\longrightarrow C((B_{X^\ast},w^\ast))$, and try to find a separable $X$ that does the job via this canonical map. Whilst such a map is necessarily strictly cosingular when $X$ is reflexive, there

Comment: are certainly reflexive spaces $X$ for which the adjoint of this canonical embedding is strictly singular, e.g. take $X$ to be the dual of the space constructed by Tsirelson, so that $X^\ast$ does not contain any super-reflexive subspace; since a reflexive subspace of $L_1(\mu)$ is super-reflexive, the adjoint is necessarily strictly singular in this case. There may actually be a good, easy reason why the adjoint of the canonical embedding of $X$ into $C((B_{X^\ast},w^\ast))$ is strictly singular whenever $X$ is reflexive, but I can't think of such a reason off the top of my head.

Comment: (The point of my last remark was that it may be easy to see that it is necessary to look at non-reflexive spaces with respect to the canonical embeddings.) Besides the isomorphic preduals of $\ell_1$ containing no copy of $c_0$, I think Gowers constructed a space containing no copy of $c_0$ or $\ell_1$ nor any infinite dimensional reflexive subspace; I know nothing about that space, but I guess it might be worth a look.

Comment: P.S. my operating system uses a stupid spell-check that evidently changes 'predual' to 'prequel' without consulting me first; sorry.

Comment: @Philip: Every weakly compact operator from an $L_1$ space is strictly singular because $L_1$ spaces have the Dunford-Pettis property.

Comment: Philip: Thanks for showing me this proof. I like the general direction. I had not thought about any of the things you mentioned. For some reason I only consider C(K) spaces when forced. I'm more comfortable with sequence spaces. As for the Gowers example you mentioned, I was thinking along those lines. There are other examples (due to Argyros and coauthors) of spaces withe the same (and more) properties. Recently, Argyros showed (this is contained in my most recent paper with him) that one of these spaces gives an example of a space such that every quotient has non-separable dual.  

Comment: ...thereby solving a problem Rosenthal and I raised 40 (sic) years ago.  

Comment: @Bill: of course! Silly me. @Kevin: I've only had a brief look, but that space of Argyros is remarkable in it's properties discussed in your paper with him. Anyway, I've enjoyed thinking about this question a little; please let me know if you happen to find the answer :) .

Comment: Shortly after the discussion above it occurred to me that one of the main features of Pelczynski's example is that it is the embedding of a Banach space into its second dual, and such embeddings never have strictly singular adjoint because the adjoint is the canonical projection of the third dual onto the first dual (in hindsight, all very obvious!). So to find a counterexample one could try to find $X$ with $X^{\ast\ast}$ separable and the canonical embedding of $X$ into $X^{\ast\ast}$ strictly cosingular; I (naively) wonder if a James-Lindenstrauss type of construction is worth considering?

Comment: Philip: With George Androulakis I proved that if a space has the property that every subspace contains either a boundedly complete basic sequence or a copy of $c_0$ then every strictly cosingular operator's adjoint is strictly singular. This implies, by an old result of Johnson-Rosenthal, that if $Y$ has separable dual and $T:X \to Y$ is strictly cosingular then it's adjoint is strictly singular. So, to use your idea, one should consider the space of James whose triple dual is non-separable, but it's double dual is separable.  